# Get vue.js 2.0 to work with Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to setup `Vue.js 2.0` with `Laravel 5.3`. I would like to put the `<router-view> </router-view>` within a main `App.vue` component. How do I get this to work with `Vue 2.0`.

This is not working anymore:

```
router.start(App, 'app');
```

So I tried this:

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

But that's not working for me. Do I've to pull in a package to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't mount app to any element in the HTML document.So define root level - div with unique ID for e.g app, and then do it like this `const app = new Vue({
 router,
 render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')`

Comment: So you mean this in my ```index.blade``` file? ```<div id="app"></div>```

Comment: Yes.Basically I don't know what is your complete app structure, but that should work.Check out my repo, to see how I did it https://github.com/bedakb/vuewp/tree/master/public/app/themes/vuewp, visit app directory to see vue stuff - index.php is place where is my #app

Comment: Cool that works thanks! But is it best practise?  Going to take a look at that repo.

Comment: I don't see any issue with this approach.You always have to say Vue where to render itself.

Comment: Thanks, please post your answer like an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to give a element where Vue code would be rendered.

So, you have to declare root level with unique ID, for e.g `#app` and mount it to Vue instance.

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    render: (h) => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

You can go with spread operator, instead of render function, pretty same thing, maybe a bit cleaner to read

```
const app = new Vue({
    router,
    ...App 
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030097/how-to-add-some-textfield-in-form-register-laravel-generator-infyom

Comment: @samueltoh sorry I am not Laravel guy.